# pyspark MlLib: exclude a column value in a row

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to create an RDD of `LabeledPoint` from a data frame, so I can later use it for MlLib.

The code below works fine if `my_target` column is the first column in sparkDF. However, if `my_target` column is not the first column, how do I modify the code below to exclude `my_target` to create a correct LabeledPoint?

```
import pyspark.mllib.classification as clf
labeledData = sparkDF.rdd.map(lambda row: clf.LabeledPoint(row['my_target'],row[1:]))

logRegr = clf.LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(labeledData)
```

That is, `row[1:]` now exclude the value in the first column; if I want to exclude value in column N of row, how do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [(1,21,31,41),(2,22,32,42),(3,23,33,43),(4,24,34,44),(5,25,35,45)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(a,["foo","bar","baz","bat"])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|foo|bar|baz|bat|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 21| 31| 41|
|  2| 22| 32| 42|
|  3| 23| 33| 43|
|  4| 24| 34| 44|
|  5| 25| 35| 45|
+---+---+---+---+

>>> N = 2 
# N is the column that you want to exclude (in this example the third, indexing starts at 0)
>>> labeledData = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row['foo'],row[:N]+row[N+1:]))
# it is just a concatenation with N that is excluded both in row[:N] and row[N+1:]

>>> labeledData.collect()
[LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0,21.0,41.0]), LabeledPoint(2.0, [2.0,22.0,42.0]), LabeledPoint(3.0, [3.0,23.0,43.0]), LabeledPoint(4.0, [4.0,24.0,44.0]), LabeledPoint(5.0, [5.0,25.0,45.0])]
```